# Upper Bound of Poisson Distribution's Right Tail

Tags: inequality, poisson-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

In the textbook ***Algorithms*** (4th edition, by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne), page 466 says:

for the classical Poisson distribution: we assume variable k has a pdf  $$\frac{\alpha ^{k}e^{-\alpha }}{k!},$$

then we have the following probability inequality to estimate the upper bound of right tail:

$$Prob(k>t\alpha )<\left (\frac{\alpha e}{t}  \right )^t e^{-\alpha } .$$

How does one prove this inequality?

Comment: I'm going to prove it in the more general case: let $x$ such that $x > \alpha$, and $ t> 0$: 
We then have : $$ \mathbb{P}(X \geq x) = \mathbb{P}(tX \geq tx) = \mathbb{P}(e^{tX} \geq e^{tx}) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}\big[e^{tX}\big]}{e^{tx}} $$
By markov's inequality since $e^{tX}$ is a positive random variable.
then by taking $t = \log(x/a) \gt 0$ you get the result. You can prove the same result when $x < a$ by considering $e^{-tX}$ instead.

Comment: $$\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{tk} e^{-\alpha}\alpha ^k / k! = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\alpha}(\alpha e^t)^k / k! = e^{-\alpha}e^{\alpha e^{t}} $$